# List of Mathematics areas to learn for understanding the Algorithm Analysis books (like Introduction to Algorithms)

Tags: algorithm

Can someone give a brief list of Mathematics areas (like functions, calculus etc.,) to learn for understanding the Algorithm Analysis books (like Introduction to Algorithms)?

Comment: It will be easier if you tell us what you already know.

Comment: start reading, learn the concepts on the way.

Comment: @Alexandre C - thanks for your response. Actually I did my degree in mathematics itself. But it's on long time (12 years!!!) back. So before starting the book just want to refresh those concepts as I want to give an in-depth read of those algorithms. By the way one more point is I want to do M.S. degree in A.I. This is my prepartion for that. I am very passionate about the A.I. and research. Have I answered your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with discrete mathematics. That would probably give you the best computational basis and intuition for what computer algorithms are about in terms of working with sets and discrete numbers in general. Also, something on data structures and algorithms would help as well. This would give you good background on things like sorting arrays, efficient searches etc. You could then move on to books on artificial intelligence (my best guess), but by this time you should definitely be ready to read some algorithms books. IMO, that is.

**UPDATE**
Also, calculus never hurts either if you're working with minimization/maximization/optimization problems. That might or might not bee needed depending on the specific algorithms you'd like to work with.

Answer (score 2):

To start with:

- number theory, especially induction.
- basic set theory, sets and functions.
- basic calculus, limits.
- logarithms
- discrete math (combinations, permutations, etc)
- generating functions (adv. discrete math).

Comment: thanks. I got what I wanted from this.

Answer (score 0):

For Introduction to Algorithms the only things you really need to know are induction and some basic set theory. For the more advanced parts you also need to know some linear algebra and probability theory.